# Can Passport save the user object not in req.user?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Passport saves its user object in `req.user` by default. Can I configure it to save it someplace else, like `req.whatever`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any name. Here is how to configure it.

```
 app.configure(function() {
     app.use(passport.initialize({ userProperty: 'yourName' }));
 });
```

Comment: Any way to define a different `userProperty` for different strategies?

Comment: You can add in the options hash when mounting the startegy. Eg.
passport.authenticate('twitter', { /*other options8 here*/ userProperty: 'yourName'});